# Differential Equation with a Motorboat

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A motorboat and its load weigh 2150N. Assuming the propeller force is constant and equal to 110 newtons and water resistance is equal numerically to 6.7V Newton where V is the velocity at any instant in m/s, and the boat starts from rest determine the speed and the distance traveled at the end of 10 seconds.

Answer is 22.72 m/s

If you layout the freebody diagram we should get the equation:

( am i wrong? maybe freebody diagrams are reserved for things that aren't moving)

```
 110 = 6.7(dx/dt)
```

derive if we get 0 = 6.7*acceleration; which is a dead end.

Integrate then:

```
 110t = 6.7x
```

plug in 10 seconds in t; I don't get the right answer... What am I supposed to do? Need hint especially how to construct the model/differential equation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with Newton's Law of Motion:

$$\sum F=ma$$

The mass of the boat and it's load is $m=\frac{2150}{g}\approx 216.16$

The sum of the forces is $110 - 6.7V$.

Thus, the equation for motion becomes:

$$216.16\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+6.7\frac{dx}{dt}-110=0.$$

Solve using your favorite technique for constant coefficient nonhomogeneous ODE. (The method of undetermined coefficients should suffice.)

Note that the solution to this equation does indeed have $x(10)=22.722\ m$.

edit:

The velocity equation is first order, linear.

$$216.16\frac{dV}{dt}+6.7V=110$$